# Is it possible to update the searchindex for only one item?

Tags: search, crawling, splistitem, updatelistitems, indexed-column

Is it possible to update the searchindex for only on specific item. I'm search some tasklists through keywordsearch and showing them in a webpart. Then I have a custom action which changes the status of a taskitem.

The problem is that after I changed the item the item stays in the webpart because it's in the keywordsearch because there was no new crawl.

So is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to update the searchindex for just one item. An incremental crawl is necessary to update the index.

Maybe it's possible to build the webpart not using the searchindex?

Answer (score 2):

If your data source is within a site collection, use a Content Query Web Part and filter on the Task content type, or otherwise use SPSiteDataQuery.

If it's split across site collections, you can only use search, and the indexing can only occur on a content source, as Anita mentioned.